# TestNG I can't properly configure my classpath

Tags: java, testng, noclassdeffounderror

I'm running my testng tests using ant. I get a noclassdeffounderror. I believe it is becuase I'm not setting my classpath properly but I can't seem to figure it out. `

```
<!-- This is the command that will be run when the tests are run from outside the vob and for 
SWIT purposes. The only test that should be run is the SWIT group which is the only test
needed for SWIT in the jar file. -->
<target name="run-swit-tests">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="touch.time" pattern="MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_aa" offset="-5" unit="hour" />
    </tstamp>

    <echo>Exluding non-SWIT groups: ${nonswit.groups}</echo>

    <testng outputdir="reports" 
        haltonfailure="false" verbose="2" excludedgroups="${nonswit.groups}">
        <classpath>
               <pathelement path="${TestClasses}"/>
               <pathelement path="${Libs}"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=foo.xml" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.coherence.override=bar.xml" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage=false" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.pof.enabled=true" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.coherence.management=all" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dtangosol.coherence.member=${user.name}-${touch.time}" />

        <jvmarg value="-javaagent:lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar" />

        <classfileset dir="." includes="**/Test*.class" excludes="**/Abstract*.class ${excluded.tests}"/>

        <reporter>
            <property name="generateGroupsAttribute" value="true" />
        </reporter>
    </testng>
</target>`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.This is the error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the lib folder I had all my jars in was fine but the path declaration was wrong somehow. This is what I added to solve the problem.
`<path id="testng.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${Libs}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>` I removed the Libs pathelement from the ant task and replaced it with a reference to the testng.classpath and all my classes were found.